# How to use inner case in oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table employee which has records of data:

```
select * from offc.employee;
```

[image]

Some people have left the office so they have `leave_date` and some people are still working which they dont have `leave_date`.
So,I only filtered the employee who has no `leave_date` in one query and employee with leave_date at another query and merged them using `UNION`.So,I write the query:

```
SELECT emp_id, 
       emp_name, 
       dob, 
       dept_id, 
       join_date, 
       leave_date, 
       line1, 
       line2, 
       salary, 
       salary upgraded_salary 
FROM   offc.employee 
WHERE  leave_date IS NOT NULL 
UNION 
SELECT emp_id, 
       emp_name, 
       dob, 
       dept_id, 
       join_date, 
       leave_date, 
       line1, 
       line2, 
       salary, 
       CASE 
              WHEN sysdate-join_date>5 THEN salary*1.5 
              WHEN sysdate-join_date<3 THEN salary*1.25 
              WHEN sysdate-join_date<1 THEN salary*1.01 
              ELSE salary 
       END upgraded_salary 
FROM   offc.employee 
WHERE  leave_date IS NULL;SELECT emp_id, 
       emp_name, 
       dob, 
       dept_id, 
       join_date, 
       leave_date, 
       line1, 
       line2, 
       salary, 
       CASE 
              WHEN leave_date IS NOT NULL THEN 
                     CASE 
                            WHEN leave_date-join_date>5 THEN salary*1.5 
                            WHEN leave_date-join_date<3 THEN salary*1.25 
                            WHEN leave_date-join_date<1 THEN salary*1.01 
                            ELSE salary 
                     END upgraded_salary 
              ELSE salary 
       END 
FROM   offc.employee 
WHERE  leave_date IS NOT NULL;
```

I got the correct output as I was expecting:

[image]
But I also tried using it in single query where I needed the inner case,I am being confused in using nested case.But I tried using nested case but its not working.So,If i can do it from nested case statement then,My query can be optimized.So,I tried as:

```
SELECT emp_id, 
       emp_name, 
       dob, 
       dept_id, 
       join_date, 
       leave_date, 
       line1, 
       line2, 
       salary, 
       CASE 
              WHEN leave_date IS NOT NULL THEN 
                     CASE 
                            WHEN leave_date-join_date>5 THEN salary*1.5 
                            WHEN leave_date-join_date<3 THEN salary*1.25 
                            WHEN leave_date-join_date<1 THEN salary*1.01 
                            ELSE salary 
                     END upgraded_salary 
              ELSE NULL 
       END 
FROM   offc.employee 
WHERE  leave_date IS NOT NULL;
```

I got the error: `ORA-00905: missing keyword`

Since ,I need the same output,Is it possible to get using nested case statement?

Comment: i have edited the sql please see it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is issue with aliasing

```
SELECT emp_id, 
       emp_name, 
       dob, 
       dept_id, 
       join_date, 
       leave_date, 
       line1, 
       line2, 
       salary, 
       CASE WHEN leave_date IS NOT NULL 
       THEN 
          CASE WHEN leave_date-join_date > 5 THEN salary*1.5 
               WHEN leave_date-join_date < 3 THEN salary*1.25 
               WHEN leave_date-join_date < 1 THEN salary*1.01 
               ELSE salary 
          END -- upgraded_salary -- issue in your query, 
              -- name of alias should be after last END
       END upgraded_salary -- alias name shoild be here
FROM   offc.employee ;
--WHERE  leave_date IS NOT NULL; -- WHERE Condition not needed
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 3):

Don't put the word "upgraded_salary" after the inner case, put it after the outer one

There's also not much point in your outer case statement because your where clause filters to only where leave date is not null so the outer CASE WHEN will always be true, the ELSE will never be true

[image]

Comment: I did also want to point out that "dateX-dateY" in oracle gives the number of days between the dates. Did you really intend to have salary increases after 1 day, 3 days and 6 days? It seems a short time, perhaps you meant years?

Comment: i know it,but since my case was not working ,my main problem was in case... i need to divide by 365